# What's the deal with declaring empty array's to $scope at the beginning of a function? (in AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Why do I see stuff like this:

```
$scope.formData ={};
```

In this case (if used for forms), I'm assuming it's for clearing the previous data (in this case a form) if it were to be called before it's populated? Why can't `formData` just be declared when its actually being decared when it's getting its data?

Comment: Because properties of `formData` are being used in `view` as a `n-model` for elements

Comment: this is not an array this is empty object and it is for use define properties in  scope when you want to assign or retrive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of declaring things only once (when the controller is loaded) is to make sure that angular watches the same object for the whole livetime of the corresponding scope.

For example:
You declare an array when the controller loads
`$scope.myArray = []`

Later you manipulate that array by some function **without** creating a new array!

```
$scope.myFunction = function(){
  //push something 
  $scope.myArray.push(value)
  //empty the array
  $scope.myArray.length = 0
}
```

Note that you dont't use `$scope.myArray = []` again in the function because that would declare a new array while angular is still watching the original one. That would lead to unrecognized changes to your model which will not be reflected in the view.

Comment: So in your example case shouldn't there be "$scope.myArray =[];" right after your function is declared?

Comment: before or after doesn't matter as long as the array variable is declared only once.